# adding the permil symbol to isotope plots in siar or siber

Tags: r

On some computers, the following code used in conjunction with the packages siar and SIBER does not render the delta and/or permil symbol correctly in the axes labels. Instead, either a blank axis label, or text such as "\u2030" is rendered in its place.

```
plot(0,xlab = expression(paste(delta^13,"C (\u2030)")))
```

Answer (score 1):

One often encountered problem is that your computer's region settings (i.e. your operating system, not the applications R or Rstudio) is set to use a non-UTF8 character set. If you type

```
Sys.setlocale()
```

in the R command window, you should see something like

"en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8/C/en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8"

which for me means I'm using UTF-8 in english with Irish region settings.

If you don't see UTF-8 then the \u2030 and other character codes won't work